# Problemas al descargar archivos desde Github en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, github

Hola a todos tengo un programa en github llamado [YgoproPatcher](https://github.com/Armagedon13/YgoProPatcher) se encarga de actualizar un juego si detecta cambios en github por ej en el repo de [cdb](https://github.com/Armagedon13/YgoproEs-CDB) si detecta que cambio, los vuelve a descargar para tener las ultimas cartas, usa un sistema de SHAs para detectar los cambios.
 Ahora el problema es que me descarga el juego, los archivos CDB los descarga también, pero cuando termina, los elimina y no tengo idea de porque.

```
//Descarga CDB usando github
    private async Task<List<string>> DownloadCDBSFromGithub(string destinationFolder)
    {

        List<string> listOfCDBs = GitAccess.GetAllFilesWithExtensionFromYGOPRO("/", ".cdb");
        string cdbFolder = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, "locales/es-ES");
        if (!await FileDownload("cards.cdb", cdbFolder, Data.GetStringsWebsite(), true))
        {
            await FileDownload("cards.cdb", cdbFolder, Data.GetStringsWebsite(), true);
        }
        progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Maximum = listOfCDBs.Count));
        List<string> listOfDownloadedCDBS = new List<string>() { Path.Combine(cdbFolder, "cards.cdb") };
        if (await FileDownload("prerelease.cdb", cdbFolder, Data.GetStringsWebsite(), true))
        {
            listOfDownloadedCDBS.Add(Path.Combine(cdbFolder, "prerelease.cdb"));
        }
        if (await FileDownload("preupdate.cdb", cdbFolder, Data.GetStringsWebsite(), true))
        {
            listOfDownloadedCDBS.Add(Path.Combine(cdbFolder, "preupdate.cdb"));
        }
        List<Task> downloadList = new List<Task>();
        foreach (string cdb in listOfCDBs)
        {
            await FileDownload(cdb, cdbFolder, Data.GetStringsWebsite(), true);
            listOfDownloadedCDBS.Add(Path.Combine(cdbFolder, cdb));
            progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar.Increment(1)));

        }
        while (downloads > 1 - throttleValue)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        return listOfDownloadedCDBS;
    }
        //Descarga lista y strings
    private async Task GitHubDownload(string destinationFolder)
    {
        Status.Invoke(new Action(() => { Status.Text = "Updating card databases from YGOProES CDB."; }));
        List<string> CDBS = new List<string>();

        CDBS = await DownloadCDBSFromGithub(destinationFolder);
        await FileDownload("lflist.conf", Path.Combine(YgoProEsPath.Text), Data.GetStringsWebsite(), true);
        await FileDownload("strings.conf", Path.Combine(YgoProEsPath.Text, "locales/es-ES"), Data.GetStringsWebsite(), true);
        progressBar.Invoke(new Action(() => { progressBar.Value = progressBar.Maximum; }));

        //DownloadUsingCDB(CDBS, destinationFolder);

    }
```

y los repositorios los llamo desde clase "data"

```
static class Data
{

    public static string GetPicWebsite()
    {
        return "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Armagedon13/YgoproEs-Pics/";
    }
    public static string GetBetaLuaWebsite()
    {
        return "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Armagedon13/YgoproEs-Scripts/";
    }
    public static string GetStringsWebsite()
    {
        return "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Armagedon13/YgoProEs-CDB/";
    }
    public static string YgoProESOwner = "Armagedon13";
    public static string version = "V1.0.0";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo hacia falta poner el /master en el raw github:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Armagedon13/YgoProEs-CDB/master/